# Why does the wc command count one more character than expected?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

The following is the content stored in my file

```
This is my Input
```

So, using `wc -c` command we can get the number of characters stored in the file.

My expected output for above file that edited by using Vim in Ubuntu is 16. But, `wc -c` command returns `17`.

Why is the output like this? There isn't even a carriage return at end of line. So, what is the 17th character?

Comment: There is one extra count for newline.

Comment: But, I didn't enter any new line. I just open the vim and enter the content and simply close. I didn't press the enter.

Comment: Then vim is a well-behaved editor that automatically adds a trailing newline at the end of the last line in a file.  `hexdump -C` your file if you want to see the bytes.

Comment: Use `od -c` to see the characters in the file including new lines rtc

Answer (score 12):

Of course you had enter. Maybe you can't see it. Consider these two examples:

```
echo -n "This is my Input" | wc -c
16
```

Because `-n` is for avoiding enter, but

```
echo "This is my Input" | wc -c
17
```

Look at this example too see the new line:

[image]

#### How to see newline?

```
echo "This is my Input" | od -c
```

`od` dumps files in octal and other formats. `-c` selects ASCII characters or backslash escapes.

And here is an example for file and usage of `od`:

[image]

Comment: echo  "This is my Input". Ok. In this line, you have enter or not

Comment: in this case you have enter

Comment: but with -n you don't have enter

Comment: where. It is just a string literal. Is it right or not

Comment: at the end of the string you have an enter too

Comment: Not really. Consider `foo="This is my input"`. The string has no newline in it, BUT if you try to count its charaters with `echo "$foo" | wc -c`, a newline is added by the `echo` command. To count characters in a string in bash, use `${#foo}`.

Comment: I added an image look at to see the newline

Comment: Ok. Here '\n' is added by echo.So, the output is 17. If We pass the input through file like "wc -c a.txt"

Comment: @Edheal had a perfect comment for you post: echo "This is my Input" | od  -c     try it to see the newline

Comment: @FattanehTalebi I didn't say that is wrong. That's right. My question is "wc -c a.txt". The output is 17. But, the expected output is 16. I am also using the following method. od -c a.txt. At that time it shows only 16. Here, the '\n' is not added. So, why the wc shows 17. what is the extra one character. It is from file or '\n' which we type to execute the command in terminal.

Comment: @mohanraj oh I got what you mean, ok I'll check it

Comment: @FattanehTalebi Please come out from echo and try to understand my problem. The following is the output for my file if we use od. And Here, there is no '\n'.  $ od -c b.txt   
0000000   T   h   i   s       i   s       m   y       i   n   p   u   t  
0000020  
$

Comment: @mohanrajl, sorry I couldn't find any answers.

Answer (score 1):

The input string you are giving as input has no enter/new line, but echo is assigning enter/newline to it. And `wc -c` reads enter or newline from given by the `echo` command.

For example

```
echo k | wc -c
```

returns 2 because 1 for `k` and 1 for new line appended by `echo`.

While

```
echo -n k | wc -c
```

returns 1 because `-n` suppresses the newline.

But `wc -c` always reads newline.

You can try

```
printf k | wc -c
```

It returns 1.

See what it does in file:

```
bash-4.1$ echo 1234 > newfile
bash-4.1$ cat newfile
1234
bash-4.1$ cat -e newfile
1234$
bash-4.1$ printf 1234 > newfile
bash-4.1$ cat newfile
1234bash-4.1$ cat -e newfile
1234bash-4.1$
```

Comment: But, I pass the input through file only. like "wc -c a.txt"

Comment: okay try this.  echo "This is my Input" > a.txt then run wc -c a.txt and printf "This is my Input" > a.txt and then wc -c a.txt. You know the difference I am talking about.

Comment: Iam using ubuntu. Editor is vim

Comment: I am using Linux and shell is ksh and editor vi. You can test this on command prompt.run echo "My" , in output you will get next prompt in newline and run echo -n "My" or printf "My" , in output you will get prompt just after the My string.

Answer (score 1):

In Linux, when Vim saves buffers, it will terminate every line by appending line terminator of new line.

You can open your file and input `:!xxd` to view hex-dump or directly use `hexdump yourfile` command.

```
0000000: 5468 6973 2069 7320 6d79 2049 6e70 7574  This is my Input
0000010: 0a                                       .
~                                                                                                                                 
~                                                                                                                                 
~
```

In there you can see, the file have appended `0a` in the end of file.

So when you use `wc -c` to get the number of this file, it will return **17**  that includes the new line symbol.

Answer (score -1):

You have `17` because of the `/0` chaeracter.

Comment: You have a couple of typos here `/0` instead of `\0` and `chaeracter` versus `character`.  The extra character being counted by **wc -c** isn't a null (`0`) it's a line terminator, likely a `\n`.  In a DOS formatted file you'd get 18 because it would be a two byte line terminator `\r\n`.