# Can someone explain why the outcome isn’t the same?

Tags: python, echo, wc

I’m learning bash and Python. So I try to solve most questions with both Bash and Python. That’s how I ended up with trying to get the length of a string in both Bash and Python, and wc is giving back a different number. Searched the internet to find an answer, but didn't find it.

```
$ echo "ensPpaJxUanRSxRzWSqMcLrYZDhkCp" | wc -c
      31
====
$ echo "ensPpaJxUanRSxRzWSqMcLrYZDhkCp" | wc -m
      31
====
$ string="ensPpaJxUanRSxRzWSqMcLrYZDhkCp"
$ echo ${#string}                          
30
====
>>> print(len("ensPpaJxUanRSxRzWSqMcLrYZDhkCp"))
30
```

Comment: You could have demonstrated this with a short string so the length is immediately obvious.

Comment: Presumably the difference is that echo appends a newline and wc counts it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WC command in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31584361/wc-command-in-linux)

Comment: Yes, learned a lot thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

echo produces a new-line which is counted as an additional character, as @khelwood comments:

```
$ echo "ensPpaJxUanRSxRzWSqMcLrYZDhkCp" | python -c 'import sys; print(list(sys.stdin))' 
['ensPpaJxUanRSxRzWSqMcLrYZDhkCp\n']
```

Comment: `echo "foo" | hd`.